# Is there any other way to get list of installed softwares on windows 10 other than muicache

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-10, windows-10-universal, msdn

I am using the path HKEY_USERS\\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MUICache to get list of installed softwares on windows 10 , but there seem to be some softwares missing in it especially excel, powerpoint.I manually checked the software list on this path and some softwares are missing. Any help?

Comment: You should search here instead: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

Comment: In addition to what @Asesh said, you may also need to look at the Wow6432Node version of the uninstall registry.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the list of installed programs? Its probably easier to do that task in a way that doesn't rummage around the registry